# php emailer in mysql result loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, phpmailer

I have a mysql select statement that returns 5 rows.  The results go into a while loop and then called against the fetch_assoc() function.  At the end of this loop I have an include for phpEmailer.  The problem is that although 5 rows are returned in the select statement only the first row sends out an email.  Here is my code:

```
include "../includes/myDBConn.php";
require_once '../includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
                                            
$sql="SELECT A.client, A.clientid, A.location, DATE_FORMAT(A.GoLiveDate, '%m/%d/%Y') AS 
GoLiveDateFormat,  
A.ProgressStatus, B.SystemEngineer, C.emailAddress FROM customerinfo A 
INNER JOIN projectteam B
ON A.clientid = B.ID
left JOIN engineers C on B.SystemEngineer=C.engName
WHERE Live NOT IN (1,2) 
AND GoLiveDate < NOW() OR GoLiveDate is null";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
        $client = $row['client'];
        $engEmail = $row['emailAddress'];
        $SystemEngineer = $row['SystemEngineer'];
         
        include '../includes/PesterEmailer.php';
    }
}
```

What is going wrong?  It seems to me that for each row and seperate email should be sent because the emailer is called each time.  Is this the way?

Comment: I imagine that the file you're including contains a function definition or class definition. Once you've included it including it a second time generates a PHP error and the program dies. Consult the documentation for PesterEmailer to find the correct way to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggeston.  I'll hunt down this path.

Comment: You're using a very old version of PHPMailer, so upgrade. It looks like you might be using the old `mysql` extension too. To send to lists efficiently, base your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).